# Fatal: '/git_repos/tools.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, remote-server

I'm developing on a local windows machine and have a git repository I'd like to push to my remote dev server (mysite.com) via ssh but I keep receiving this error:

**fatal: '/git_repos/tools.git' does not appear to be a git repository**

**fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**

To clarify, I have created a folder on my remote server (git_repos/tools.git), and set up a new repo within it:

**git init --bare**

The folder is owned by "user" and user has full access privileges. I have then added the remote location to my local repo :

**git remote add origin ssh://user@mysite.com:/git_repos/tools.git**

and attempted to push the master branch up, using:

**git push -u origin master**

however I always encounter the above error. I am able to log in via SSH through putty, although I always land in the user root directory and not the "git_repos/tools.git" subfolder.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I tried initially without the leading slash but was receiving another error "could not resolve hostname mysite.com:git_repos", so I went into the .config file within the .git folder and removed the "ssh://" at the beginning of the url, and it seems to work now:

[remote "origin"]
 url = user@mysite.com:git_repos/tools.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

However I don't really understand why this would work. Any ideas what was causing the problem?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I deleted my comment. As documented in [the git book section](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols), there are two ways: `ssh://user@server/project.git` (with ssh:// and slash) or `user@server:project.git` (no ssh:// and colon instead of slash).

Comment: Sorry, is that a folder in the root directory, or a folder in your home directory? And, there's no such thing as "user root directory".

Comment: @o11c - yes sorry, I meant home directory for the "user" user. The git_repos folder is within this folder.