# fatal: Not a git repository: '/git_repos/repo' on post-receive hook

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying my best to set up my git workflow such that I can push commits from my local dev machine to a bare repo on my server and have a post-receive hook checkout the content to my remote live site, but I am getting this error:

fatal: Not a git repository: '/git_repos/repo' on post-receive hook.

The steps I have taken are:

**Remote Server (mysite.com, user="user")**

1. git init --bare on my remote server under '/git_repos/repo'
2. add a 'post-receive' file under the hooks subfolder containing:#!/bin/sh
   git --work-tree=/public --git-dir=/git_repos/repo checkout -f
3. assign execute privileges for user for post-receive  - chmod +x post-receive

**Local Server**

1. git remote add livesite user@mysite.com:git_repos/repo
2. commit changes and .. git push livesite

The shell script executes but fails with the same error each time. For reference, the remote "git_repos" and "public" folders are in the home directory for the "user" user.

Does anyone know what might be causing this to fail?

Please note that as far as I'm concerned, this issue is separate to my previous query as I was not able to push the repo to my remote server at all, however this is now resolved. Perhaps it is worth mentioning that I have tried the post-receive hook with and without the leading slash (i.e. **git-dir=git_repos/repo**) and the error message is the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal: '/git\_repos/tools.git' does not appear to be a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132539/fatal-git-repos-tools-git-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s mainly caused the path /git_repos/repo can’t be found or it's does not a git repo.

In the post-receive hook of remote server, you should specify the **full paths** of `git_repos/repo` and `public` for `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options.

Assume the full path for `git_repos/repo` is `/home/user/git_repos/repo`, and the full path for `public` is `/home/user/public`. Then you should change the **post-receive hook** as:

```
#!/bin/sh 
git --work-tree=/home/user/public --git-dir=/home/user/git_repos/repo checkout -f
```